# Flutter BottomNavigationBarItem update variable in main page from different page

Tags: flutter, dart

we have a BottomNavigationBarItem and one icon has Notification counter,

we want to update that counter (notificationCounter) from any page
Like from Business(), School(),

how we achieve this?

---

Please ignore this repeated text i had to do it because stack overflow telling me i have a lot of code and not enough  of text they are not allowing me to put my question( this bug need to be reported to stack overflow) because im not having a lot of code its normal in flutter and my question is short

### thanks

```
    class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  int notificationCounter = 0;

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Business(),
    School(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
           BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Badge(
                    showBadge: true,
                    badgeContent: Text(notificationCounter.toString(), style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.white)),
                    animationType: BadgeAnimationType.scale,
                    shape: BadgeShape.circle,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  ),
                  label: 'Home',
                ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it for you,
Declare `int _currentIndex = 0;` in the state of your class

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  backgroundColor: kMainBgColor,
  onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      });
  },
  selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
  currentIndex: _currentIndex,
  items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        backgroundColor: kCardBgColor,
        activeIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/home.png',width: 24,height: 24,color: kNavVioletColor,),
        icon: Image.asset('assets/images/home.png',width: 24,height: 24,),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.update),
        label: "New"
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.done),
        label: "New"
        )
      ],
  ),
```

Comment: sorry im not asking about the index update im asking about the notificationCounter variable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at using the Providers package for ChangeNotifierProvider. Once you wrap your main build with a changenotifier, let the changenotifier file handle values like counters, then it will update the relevant widgets automatically (as the providers are wrapped around / accessed by all your widgets).

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html
https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: is there a way to do it without provider

Comment: You can use the standard update state method: setState(() { });   however this needs to be called from within your bottomNavigationBar, so the widget needs to be a stateful widget (therefore create a separate widget for it) and you need a way to call that widget to update it's state, or have it check for updates to a value everx X seconds using a timer. But I would advise using a provider instead, it makes it much simpler.